# Copying a table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using .NET Core 2.2 and Entity Framework what is the easiest way to copy a database table to a new database table.

i.e. creating an archive copy of that table.

Comment: I think using pure SQL would be the best here. Bringing it into memory and writing it back to the database does not seem necessary.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to create a new table first and then copy all the records from the existing table into the new. Is that correct? Could you also please tell us what is the requirement to create an archive copy? If it is for maintenance, it should not be a part of your application code.

Comment: it is to create a full table copy of all the data

Comment: @Magnus yes but how?

Comment: @Coppermill added an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using raw sql in EntityFrameworkCore to accomplish what you need.

```
    dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, 
    "INSERT INTO TABLE2
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1" );
```

Answer (score 0):

if memory is not an issue

```
var sourceFiles = _context.SourceTables.ToList();

foreach(var sourceFile in sourceFiles)
{
    //if matching entity
    _context.DestinationTables.Add(sourceFile);
    //if not matching
    var destination = new DestinationEntity 
    {
        Prop1 = sourceFile.Prop1,
        //other properties
    }
    _context.DestinationTables.Add(destination);


    //if need to remove
    _context.SourceTables.Remove(sourceFile);
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I can see what you are doing here, is it not possible to run this directly on the SQL server from the EntityFramework?

Comment: @Coppermill wait i am confused? as an SQL query?